# Как брать индексы в двумерном массиве

Tags: lua

У меня есть двумерный массив

```
 local array = {{1, "t"}, {23, "p"}}
```

И я нигде не могу найти как  доступиться к  например к 1 и t по отдельности. 
Не кидайте тапками.  Скиньте линк где про это написано. Сам я не нашел. Или наведите пример . например я циклом иду, как мне доступатся по отдельности в нем к ним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что именно у вас вызывает трудности?

```lua
local t = {
  {1, 2, 3},
  {4, 5, 6},
  {7, 8, 9},
}

print(t[1][1])
print(t[2][2])
print(t[3][3])
```

```
1
5
9
```

Цикл `for`:

```lua
for y = 1, #t do
  for x = 1, #t[y] do
    print(t[y][x])
  end
end
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: тоесть например чтобы доступится в моем случаи 1 - 1,1

Comment: а к t- 1,2 чтобы доступится. я правильно понял?

Comment: но как мне в форе это записать? for index = 1, 10 do   print (array[index][index] ) я так вывожу. но мне нужно например вывести array[1][2]

Comment: @VovaMakarovych  Добавил пример цикла.  Вам нужны два.